# $PATH prolems in Ubuntu

Tags: paths

I have an application named delphi in Delphi_Dp directory.
Its PATH is `/usr/kalyan/Downloads/Delphi_Dp`

I have done export
`PATH=$PATH:/usr/kalyan/Downloads/Delphi_Dp`

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/kalyan/Downloads/Delphi_Dp' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

But in terminal, when I type delphi, it is showing Command not found.

Please Help..

Comment: have you tried to execute this binary directly in the specific folder using `./delphi`? is the binary executable then? it seems a simple question...

Comment: Have you logged out and back in again for change to take effect.  If yes simple check that the file is where it should be and path is correct.  Edit the question to include the output of `ls -la /usr/kalyan/Downloads/Delphi_Dp/de*; echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Though some people may advice against this, however, with hindsight, I have never experienced any negative impact of this. Instead of exporting the `PATH` to `.bash_profile`, export to `.bashrc` as follows:

`echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/kalyan/Downloads/Delphi_Dp' >> ~/.bashrc`